# Using Typeform for making product orders and paying with PapPal

Tags: php, html, paypal, typeform

I am making a Typeform as an order form for my product that has a lot of customization so Typeform is perfect for it, however Stripe payments are not available in my country. Does anyone have experience with integrating Paypal into Typeform order form? Possibly by using page redirect and then passing the price to the paypal payment button and somehow linking the form submission ID with the payment ID?

Or are there any other services like Typeform that are so easy to use and look great?

Thank you for any help / suggestions

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask for advice about which tools or services are best to use. I recommend asking on a site like Quora or r/AskProgramming instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option in your case would be using the redirect after submit feature.

If you're using Typeform as an order form then probably you're using the calculator feature to get the final price, so you have some kind of PRO account. I'm not sure how the PayPal API works, but if you use redirect after submit (in the form settings) then you can add the calculated "score" (price) as a querystring there.

For details on how to set it up, checkout [Typeform's help center](https://www.typeform.com/help/)

Comment: What @anabella is saying is a good approach!

You can also have a similar flow using "Respondent Notifications", they will receive an email once they are done ordering. The email should contain a link to pay on PayPal, using the "price" variable as anabella described.

Answer (score 0):

Quill Forms has a native integration with Paypal and supports subscriptions as well.